# Javascript onload not firing in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I'm creating a new window using the following:

```
var windowX = window.open('page.html', 'newWindow', 'width=600,height=600');
```

The new window is just a blank html page that contains javascript which constructs a new object, I then use that object with some more javascript that I inject after the page has loaded.

My solution works in chrome and firefox but does not appear to work in IE11. The alert does not show, nor does the following code.

```
windowX.onload = function() {
    //I've added the alert just to see if the onload is firing...
    windowX.alert('hello!');
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.language = 'JavaScript';
    script.src = '/scripts/newScript.js';
    windowX.document.head.appendChild(script);
};
```

I've attempted to use jQuery `$(windowX).ready(...)` & `$(windowX).load(...)` which still works in chrome but with no success in IE11.

Comment: Any error messages in the console?

Comment: @Teemu No, however it's difficult to tell as I cannot view the console until a second or so after the window appears.

Comment: The code is executed in the main window, the console should be avaible all the time.

Comment: @Teemu Then no, no errors at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the problem is that IE11 runs `window.open()` as a synchronous task, preventing any further javascript from running until the window has opened and loaded, so the onload event that is declared afterwards is never fired because the new window has already 'loaded'.

To get around this I check if the users browser is IE11 and fire the load event using jquery:

```
if (!!window.MSInputMethodContext && !!document.documentMode) {
    $(windowX).trigger('load');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is ok - you cannot work with properties of unfinished object ("Unable to set property 'onload' of undefined or null reference"), but this code works in IE11 (do not need to load empty page):

```
var windowX = window.open('');
windowX.alert('hello!');
var script = windowX.document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.language = 'JavaScript';
script.src = '/scripts/newScript.js';
windowX.document.head.appendChild(script);
```

But you are right those 2 browsers have them visible during loading (for example window.name does not exist in IE, but exist in these 2).

Comment: The html page I'm loading looks blank, but it contains javascript code that is required for what I'm trying to do. So I need to load a page. Also I just tested the code without loading a page and it still doesn't fire the alert.

Comment: Strange complex - would not be easier if page.html will access opener https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener instead ? Quite complicated to synchronize properly this way.

Comment: Unfortunately not, there is a lot of dynamic javascript that needs to done on the main window and passed in to the new one. I just haven't included that as it is not relevant for the problem.

Comment: @Will You can use `opener` to refer to the main window. Just make the function creating the content global, and call it from the pop-up.

Comment: Then ugly solution I used was checking document.readyState (setInterval) of new window and after it is ok execute your onload part. But you will have to make lot of ifs like if(window && window.document, etc. And even after that it may break if opened page will have connection problems, unavailable, etc. (fake) CORS errors, etc.

Comment: In case you like, can find some an old "solution" if you want - HTA checking info from foreign domain web (CORS).